# Is there any workaround to unstack a tensor along a dimension with variable length?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, reshape, tensor

I need to loop over the first dimension of which the length is variable, how can I manage to do it? If impossible any workarounds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`tf.unstack`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/unstack) along the dynamic dimension is *not supported*:

> If `value.shape[axis]` is not known, ValueError is raised.

But you can try to use [`tf.while_loop`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop) to iterate over the tensor slices. Here's an example that computes the sum:

```py
# Input tensor: trying to iterate along axis=0
x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, 3])
batch_size = tf.shape(x)[0]

def cond(x, i, _):
  return i < batch_size

def body(x, i, x_prev):
  # Do some operation with `x_prev` and `x[i]`. Here we just add the slices
  sum = x_prev + x[i]
  return x, i + 1, sum

# This means: starting from 0, apply the body, while the `cond` is true
_, _, c = tf.while_loop(cond, body, (x, 0, tf.zeros([3])))

# Test it
with tf.Session() as sess:
  data = np.arange(12).reshape([4, 3])
  print(data)

  result = sess.run(c, feed_dict={x: data})
  print(result)
```

Output:

```
[[ 0  1  2]
 [ 3  4  5]
 [ 6  7  8]
 [ 9 10 11]]

[ 18.  22.  26.]
```